# Django m2m_changed pk_set is empty

Tags: django, signals, manytomanyfield

Django version 1.10.7, I have a problem where sometimes my receiving `m2m_changed` signal on a ManyToMany field has `pk_set` empty.

The model m2m part (note it's a `self` reference):

```
class Profile(TimeStampedModel):
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", verbose_name=_("Following"), related_name="followers"
    )
```

Signal beginning part with logger:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Profile.following.through)
def profile_following_change(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs):
    logger.debug("profile_following_change - sender %s, instance %s, action %s, pk_set %s, kwargs: %s",
                 sender, instance, action, pk_set, kwargs)
```

Below an example log line with `pk_set` containing the added primary key:

```
DEBUG:socialhome:profile_following_change - 
    sender <class 'socialhome.users.models.Profile_following'>, 
    instance Profile A (profile_a@a.domain.tld), 
    action post_add, 
    pk_set {2}, 
    kwargs: {
        'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x7fa73e033908>, 
        'model': <class 'socialhome.users.models.Profile'>, 
        'using': 'default', 
        'reverse': False
    }
```

And an example with an empty `pk_set`.

```
DEBUG:socialhome:profile_following_change - 
    sender <class 'socialhome.users.models.Profile_following'>, 
    instance Profile B (profile_b@b.domain.tld), 
    action post_add, 
    pk_set set(), 
    kwargs: {
        'model': <class 'socialhome.users.models.Profile'>, 
        'reverse': False, 
        'using': 'default', 
        'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x7f001c173908>
    }
```

The two saves are both from the same code, using the following line. Note this code runs in an RQ background process, should that matter:

```
profile.following.add(user.profile)
```

Why is the `pk_set` sometimes empty, any ideas? Note that both `Profile` objects also exist before the RQ job is processed (event is triggered by doing a "follow" in the UI).

Also of note, added object *is* found in the ManyToMany field after the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but for those who get here through search like me, I got an empty pk_set when I was trying to re-add a relationship that was already added, for example, adding a **Topping** to a **Pizza** when the **Topping** was already on the **Pizza**.

Wouldn't usually try to do that, but was trying to get the signal to work. Hope this saves someone a few minutes of head-scratching.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue.